# How to dynamically change the variables of a view?

Tags: views, hooks

I create a view (eg Generic) which defaults to a mini pager 10 items.

When I visualize this view, I would like to dynamically change the number of items in the passing 3.

How? What hook to use?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102236/change-the-pager-and-the-number-of-elements-per-page-of-a-specific-view ?

Comment: Yes, ca es. I put the question more simply hope to have an answer

Comment: Still, this is a duplicate question. Please don't ask the same question twice just to get a quicker answer. Since you are still asking for code, I am going to close this question as duplicate.

Comment: The previous question has no answer